# Should you pad messages encrypted with stream ciphers?

Tags: stream-cipher, padding

Should you pad messages encrypted with stream ciphers?

The obvious answer seems to be yes, right? It obviously leaks the exact length of the plaintext.

Consider a situation where an adversary knows a user will send either $m_0$ or $m_1$. Suppose further that the adversary  observes  the decryption of $m_0$ and $m_1$-- namely, now they know the length of each message. It is now trivial to see how the adversary could differentiate  $Enc(m_0)$ from $Enc(m_1)$

From what I have seen though, padding messages encrypted with stream ciphers doesn't seem super common/ isn't done automatically in libraries like monocypher.

Comment: Note that the length of a message is not something cryptography usually tries to protect, because you always give at least an upper bound on message length. And note that the different length attack also applies to modes like CBC which do pad, especially if you're unlucky and e.g. one message is 15 byte (1 padded block) and the other is 16 byte (2 padded blocks).

Comment: If the length differs then an adversary can distinguish and has an advantage even with the block ciphers. Hiding the length is related to your scheme, not a general case in Cryptography. You can define your risks and message space to see the leaked information. Also, consider that compressing can be performed before encryption that can hide some lenght information.

Comment: This is true. Perhaps the  distinction I make is between leaking the exact length of a message, and an upper bound on it. For communication with small message sizes/ or known possible messages, this seems problematic. Do you think i should revise my question to "when does it make sense to pad messages when using stream ciphers, and if so how?"

Comment: That would be too broad a question and we prefer specific cases in your mind. You can express them with some obfuscation.